# Is it okay to expose magic tricks on skeptics?

Tags: discussion

I am aware of this question asking if:

[Are magic tricks in scope?](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1875/are-magic-tricks-in-scope)

Most magicians don't claim they are magicians, e.g. they admit their acts are tricks and not ral magic. But many people believe that the tricks are actually real and that could make them a notable claim.

For instance, I want to ask this:

*How did this magician cut himself in half?*

For example the question I want to ask is this: How did this magician cut himself in half in this YouTube [video](https://youtu.be/8BE2KBhhEZU)? It looks real I almost believe he's really cutting himself in half.

[image]

Would skeptics.se find that acceptable?

Comment: Unless the person is claiming something to be true (ie. not knowingly being a magician performing a TRICK), I don't see how it's appropriate for Skeptics.

Comment: Not only they need to claim that it's real and not a trick, but also people need to believe them

Comment: @Sklivvz - P.T. Barnum is still alive (well, the truth of his statement is, at any rate)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No? Because "How does something work?" is not on-topic. How do they get spaceships into space? How do they get the fortune into a fortune cookie? Etc.

Asking whether a claim is true is OK though: [Did David Blaine hold his breath for 17 minutes?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/22759/2703)