# My question has been closed because of it being duplicate and it isn't

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

This is the question: [Did Derren Brown use subliminal messages in this trick?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/47219/did-derren-brown-use-subliminal-messages-in-this-trick)

My question is nothing like the question it is redirecting too. That question asks for a different thing and my question asks for a different thing.

The only way I'll get a satisfactory answer is when my question is answered, the answers to that question aren't satisfying my query.

Answer (score 1):

Please have a read of the discussion here: [Are magic tricks in scope?](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1875/are-magic-tricks-in-scope)

Please also have a read of the answer of the duplicated question that directly addresses your question, particularly the quote from Derren Brown:

> I am often dishonest in my techniques, but always honest about my dishonesty. As I say in each show, 'I mix magic, suggestion, psychology, misdirection and showmanship'. I happily admit cheating, as it's all part of the game. I hope some of the fun for the viewer comes from not knowing what's real and what isn't. I am an entertainer first and foremost, and I am careful not to cross any moral line that would take me into manipulating people's real-life decisions or belief systems.

It isn't necessary to investigate whether subliminal messages work the way Derren Brown represents them, because it is not a notable claim. because **Derren Brown is a professional magician who proudly tells falsehoods for a living**.

Comment: Whether subliminal messages work(as in they are effective in changing behavior) is a valid topic for discussion on Skeptics Stack Exchange. And my question is part of this line of investigation.

Comment: Whether quantum tunnelling works is a valid topic of investigation. Whether quantum tunnelling made this coin appear from inside your ear, just because a magician told you it did, is not.

Comment: Quantum Tunneling is valid topic for Physics SE not Skeptics SE.

Comment: Your analogy fails because it is not the same, we can know in 99% of cases QT will make the coin disappear, whereas my questions subject is within realm of skeptics SE.

Comment: There should other moderators who should be involved in decided the closure of question, not just you.

Comment: I don't propose to spend any more time on this; it seems a clear case of a fictional claim being made by a talented magician who is play-acting on stage. You can edit the question to find a serious notable claim, persuade 5 regulars with enough rep to vote to reopen your existing question, and/or click on the Contact link below to discuss with StackExchange staff if you think you have not been treated fairly by any moderators.